# Mobx observable properties

Tags: properties, observable, mobx

After adding observable properties to an array with this action

```
@action
improvePrograms = function() {
    let data = this.dataPro;
    this.dataProImproved = data;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      extendObservable(this.dataProImproved[i], {
        wishedFor: false,
        inCart: false,
        sold: false
      });
    }
  };
```

I tried to change the values of the properties with:

```
  @action
  addToWishList = function(item) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.dataProImproved.length; i++) {
      if (this.dataProImproved[i].program_id === item.program_id && this.dataProImproved[i].wishedFor === false) {
        this.dataProImproved[i] = { ...this.dataProImproved[i], wishedFor: true };
        console.log("Program added to wish list: ", this.dataProImproved[i]);
        this.getWishList();
      }
    }
  };
```

everything seemed fine but the component where I use the observable property for changing colors doesn't react or rerender even when the value of the properties are changed to true.

```
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={!this.props.program.wishedFor ? this.onSelectWish : this.onDeselectWish}>
          <FontAwesome
            style={{ padding: 7 }}
            name={this.props.program.wishedFor === false ? "heart-o" : "heart"}
            size={28}
            color={!this.props.program.wishedFor ? "#c5d1e8" : "#ff1d25"}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here. The class component is decorated with @observer and injected with the store.

Comment: So I made it work passing the data array through @computed like:

Answer (score 0):

So I made it work passing the data array through:

```
@computed get getDataProImproved(){return this.dataProImproved}
```

And don't forget to slice the array before passing it to the FlatList...
Everything reacts fine...